# What noun means opposite of "slacker" but is less extreme than "overachiever"?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, antonyms

Sample sentence: "John was not a slacker. He was reliable and productive. Not quite an overachiever per se but rather a ____. What needed to be done, he always got done. No more and no less."

(Preferably one word noun to fill the blank).

Comment: "*To ensure your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word. YOU MUST INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE demonstrating how the word would be used.*" https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-requests

Comment: *eager beaver*...

Comment: _Strickland_ comes to mind…

Answer (score 3):

How about ***workhorse***?

> ***[Workhorse](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/workhorse)***
>
> NOUN
>
> 1. A horse used for work on a farm.
>
>    1.1 A person or machine that dependably performs hard work over a long period of time.
>      *‘the aircraft was the standard workhorse of Soviet medium-haul routes’*

That would be my choice.   There's also ***self-starter***:

> ***[Self-Starter](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/self-starter)***
>
> NOUN
>
> 1. A person who is sufficiently motivated or ambitious to work on their
>      own initiative without needing direction.
>      *‘he was the self-starter who worked his way up from messenger boy to account executive’*

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

A **go-getter** is someone who is productive, active, and energetic.  From the OED:

> An enterprising or ambitious person; a person who is determined or likely to succeed; an achiever.
>
> "We want to appoint young, enthusiastic and ambitious *go-getters* who want to grab hold of this opportunity and make the most of it."

It's a common phrase in US English, though I'm not sure how common it is in other dialects.

Of course, one man's "overachiever" is another man's "go-getter";  there's an inherently subjective judgement in deciding how productive is "overly" productive.

Answer (score 2):

Trouper also works as a sort of veteran of the good and bad times.

**trouper**

> An experienced or dependable worker or associate

[Collins English Dictionary, 12th Ed.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/trouper)

Answer (score 2):

A **rock**

> One that is similar to or suggestive of a mass of stone in stability,
>   firmness, or dependability: The family has been his rock during this
>   difficult time.